# How do you calibrate the extrinsic parameters?

Tags: ros, calibration, monocular-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to calibrate my camera mounted on the robot base so that I can get the transform from base_link to camera_link. i was looking for efficient and fast ways to do this and I found the following [calibration algorithm](http://vision.kuee.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Enob/proj/mirror/) which was useful because I could fix my pattern on the robot base directly and use a mirror to make it visible to the camera.

After doing some tests with that, the results were totally wrong. I also tested with a webcam mounted on my pc and I couldn't get good results.

How do the ROS community proceed with the extrinsic calibration of a monocular camera?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196096/how-do-you-calibrate-the-extrinsic-parameters?/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-10-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be interested in the [industrial_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/industrial_extrinsic_cal) package from the ROS-Industrial community. Also: [Industrial Calibration Library Update and Presentation](http://rosindustrial.org/news/2014/9/24/industrial-calibration-library-update-and-presentation).

It can be a bit involved to get it working at the moment, but that is being worked on. If you find you need help with anything, don't hesitate to send a mail to the ROS-Industrial [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev) (or ask here on ROS Answers of course).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-07-24**:
That doesn't work with melodic.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-01**:
You're commenting on a 5 year old Q&A. I'm not surprised that pkg may not work on Melodic.